# using angular animation query / stagger on existing elements?

Tags: angular, animation

im pretty new to angular and I'm trying to get my head around this.

I have a form with some input fields which I want to have fading in with each of them having slightly more delay.

But every description I entcountered is using :enter or assumes the element doesn't exist in the DOM, mine do exist before the animation though.

So I can't use query and stagger to delay my animations because they already exist? Or is it because I use ng-animate which is based on animate.css?

Here is my animation:

```
animations: [
trigger('divState', [
  state('preload', style({
    opacity: 0
  })),
  state('loaded', style({
    opacity: 1
  })),
  transition('loaded => preload', [useAnimation(fadeOutLeft, {
    params: {
      fromOpacity: 1,
      toOpacity: 0,
    }
  })]),
  transition('preload => loaded',
    query(':self',
      stagger(300, useAnimation(bounceInRight, {
        params: {
          fromOpacity: 0,
          toOpacity: 1,
          delay: 0.2,
          timing: 0.6,
          a: '100px',
        }
      }))
    )
  ),
]),
```

]

Comment: It slightly unclear how you are planning to do the animation and when

Comment: Ah oops, state is set to loaded on init; when the component is initiated all elements should bounce in one by one

but they only bounce in simultaneously